# jQuery enable Required validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a RequiredFieldValidator on my asp.net page that I would like to enable on the client side when a button is clicked and my text box is empty. My code does enable the RequredFiledValidator, however, my event still processes because Page.Isvalid is still true. How do I stop my event from firing until the text box is populated?

Here is my Required Filed:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="endExciseNumberRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="endExciseNumberTextBox" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="False" ErrorMessage="*Please Complete Excise Range." Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12px" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="dorReview" ClientIDMode="Static">*Please Complete Excise Range.</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#createUploadPackageButton").click(function ()
    {
        if ($("#endExciseNumberTextBox").val() == '')
        {

            var valendExciseNumberRequiredFieldValidator = $("[id*=endExciseNumberRequiredFieldValidator]");
        ValidatorEnable(valendExciseNumberRequiredFieldValidator[0]);


        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass second parameter as `true` to `ValidatorEnable` function

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#createUploadPackageButton").click(function ()
    {
        if ($("#endExciseNumberTextBox").val() == '')
        {

            var valendExciseNumberRequiredFieldValidator = $("[id*=endExciseNumberRequiredFieldValidator]");
        ValidatorEnable(valendExciseNumberRequiredFieldValidator[0], true);


        }

    });
});
```

Comment: added "true" parameter but the Page.IsValid is still true.

Comment: `Page.IsValid` is true on server side? If yes, then it is because you have set the `Enabled=false` for your required field validator.